# How to make an option only once selectable in react?

Tags: reactjs, tags

I'm still working on my columns interface, now I'm at the part where users can add tags to a column.
However, I want some tags to be only selectable once.
Once a specific tag has been selected/added the option should be removed from the select.
I have no idea how to achieve this.

My code is already found online in this pen: https://codepen.io/darkinfore/pen/daJxyP?editors=0110

You can add and remove tags in this pen to see it for yourself.
The adding and removing system works but I want some tags to only be added once.
I'm adding a tag after an option is selected.

**This is the code for the select hardcoded:**

```
<select value="" className="autocomplete-select" style={{border: "0px", outline: "none", width: "90px", height: "18px"}} id={props.index} onChange={props.onaddtag}>
    <option value="" disabled ></option>
    <option value="URL">URL</option>
    <option value="SUBTITLE">SUBTITLE</option>
  </select>
```

**And my onaddtag function:**

```
onaddtag(e: any){
    const array = this.state.fields.columns;
    const newArray = [ ...array[e.target.id].tags, {name: e.target.value, attributes: [] } ];
    array[e.target.id].tags = newArray;
    this.setState({ fields: { columns: array } });
    this.setState({ canSave: true });
    console.log(this.state.fields.columns);
  }
```

Can someone make this for me or explain how to achieve this?

Comment: Beware trying to log `this.state` straight after calling it - [the state updates may get run asynchronously or batched together](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), so you'll likely not get the results you're expecting.

Comment: No thats not the problem, I just don't know how to make an option only selectable once

Comment: Yeah, not saying that's the issue - just want to make sure you don't get confused if your logging doesn't give you what you expect :)

Comment: You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array to hold the tags. This would mean that each tag within each field column would be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a count variable for every element you want to control in the state and increment it every time you call a function( onaddtag() or any other function you want to call). like:-

```
state : {
countforelement1=0,
countforelement2=0
}
```

then on every element you want to control for only one click write as:-

```
<Element1 onClick=>{()=> this.state.countforelement1<=1 ? (function_to_be_called()) : null } ></Element1>
```

and for normal tags don't use any condition just call the function on onClick.

Inside the function like

```
onaddtag(){ e==Element1 ? this.setState(countforElementx+=1) : null}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I call setstate only the current component gets updated, how to update all column components?

Comment: you have to create a count variable for each element in state and in ondatatag(or any other function)   do   { e==ElementX ? this.setState(countforElementX+=1) : null} for each and every element you want to change